# sql move row from one table into another

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to do this, but I am not sure if it is wise, so I ask:  I have one table that stores any issues with software that we use at work.  If the problem becomes resolved, should I move that row to a resolved issue table, or should I only insert the issue's table pk, and whenever I query open issues use an outer join?  Just looking for industry standard on this.

Comment: I think this really depends on your design requirements.  Another option would be to have a flag in the original table as to whether something is resolved or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving rows around is almost always a bad idea. If you add additional information regarding resolved issues (e.g., who resolved it, when was it resolved, etc.), having an additional "resolutions" table with a foreign key to the "issues" table might be a good idea. Otherwise, I'd just add a `boolean` field `is_resolved` to the "issues" table and set it to `true` when the issue is resolved.

Comment: This is what I thought. I need to have more data on the resolution. Having a Boolean field is not enough information, it would become poor design if I added the resolution and the fix, etc to the issue table. Thank you for your fast response

Answer (score 3):

I think you should take one column with name status and update this column as per your choice .and use trigger to maintain this table history .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a column with a boolean: "Resolved". Set to true when the issue is resolved and find all resolved rows with "WHERE resolved=true".